# paramiko invok shell received result only

Tags: python

I check a script to connect to a Cisco with SSH.

I wish cpature only the resultat from one command (here "show arp")
Currently I capture the command and the resultat.

Someone has a solution ?

Thanks

```
import sys
from time import sleep
import paramiko
encoding = 'utf-8'

host="192.168.109.10"
command = 'show arp'
 
# Create an ssh connection and set terminal length 0
conn = paramiko.SSHClient()
conn.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
conn.connect(host, username="admin", password="admin")

router_conn = conn.invoke_shell()
print('Successfully connected to %s' % host)

router_conn.send('terminal length 0\n')
sleep(1)        # Wait for the cmd to be sent and processed
 
# Send the command and wait for it to execute
router_conn.send("show arp\n")
sleep(2)
output = router_conn.recv(65535)
print(type(output))

path = '/home/alexandre/Python_script/'
file_dst = '%s%s.txt' %(path,host)

listToStr = str(output,encoding)
 
print(type(listToStr))

new_file = open(file_dst, 'w')
new_file.write(listToStr)
```

Comment: Can you describe what issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Here the result

```
**************************************************************************
* IOSv is strictly limited to use for evaluation, demonstration and IOS  *
* education. IOSv is provided as-is and is not supported by Cisco's      *
* Technical Advisory Center. Any use or disclosure, in whole or in part, *
* of the IOSv Software or Documentation to any third party for any       *
* purposes is expressly prohibited except as otherwise authorized by     *
* Cisco in writing.                                                      *
**************************************************************************
SWITCH-3#terminal length 0
SWITCH-3#show arp
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  192.168.109.1         116   0050.56c0.0009  ARPA   Vlan1
Internet  192.168.109.10          -   0c48.73ec.8001  ARPA   Vlan1
SWITCH-3#
```

I wish only get th efollowing

```
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  192.168.109.1         116   0050.56c0.0009  ARPA   Vlan1
Internet  192.168.109.10          -   0c48.73ec.8001  ARPA   Vlan1
```